# How to manually create users with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, admin

In my rails app, I'm using devise for user registration.
Now besides the user registrations, admins should create, edit and delete user in the backend, too.
I have a problem with creating new users through that admin backend.

When I call the UsersController#new action in my browser it opens up the user entry form created by me.
When I click on the submit button the Devise::RegistrationsController#create is called but it should call my UsersController#create action.

How do I achvieve to call UsersController#create when using the user creation in the admin backend, and to call Devise::RegistrationsController#create when a user uses the registration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) add the path prefix to devise: `devise_for :users, :path_prefix => 'd'`

2) run `rake routes`:

```
user_registration POST   /d/users(.:format)   devise/registrations#create
...
users POST   /users(.:format)  users#create
```

So, the first route for `Devise::RegistrationsController`, second for your `UsersController`.

And you can simply use in the `admin/new_user.html.erb`: `form_for User.new`

Answer (score 0):

On the back of the Mikhail's answer, you can also tell devise to use any other pathname instead of 'users'. For example:

```
devise_for :users, path: 'auth'
```

would result in devise routes like /auth/sign_up, /auth/sign_in, etc. And your custom user routes would be safe.

(The full list of devise_for options can be found [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper:devise_for))